# How to style JavaFX ComboBox' popup with CSS

Tags: css, javafx

I have a bug in my JavaFX program and cannot style the list items once clicked.

You can see here everything is okay as I desired until I click on the entries. They become invisible / white. But I want to have the same font color for all entries except for the selected one.

How can I realize that? Thanks.

[image: demonstration of the bug]

CSS:

```css
.combo-box *,
.combo-box-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.combo-box-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:selected .label {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Media, String> statusColumn;
    
    
private void initTable() {  
    statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));
    statusColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String status, boolean empty) {

            if (status != null && !empty) {

                Label selectedLabel = null;

                ObservableList<Label> statuses = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for (MEDIA_STATUS stat : MEDIA_STATUS.values()) {
                    Label label = new Label(stat.getStatus());
                    if (label.getText().equals(status)) {
                        selectedLabel = label;
                    }
                    FontIcon icon = MediaStatusUtil.getIcon(stat);
                    label.setGraphic(icon);
                    statuses.add(label);
                }

                final ComboBox<Label> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(statuses);
                setGraphic(comboBox);
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(selectedLabel);
                
                // TODO: implement change listener to refresh data model
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
public enum MEDIA_STATUS {
    DELETE("DELETE"), MOVE("MOVE"), UNPROCESSED("UNPROCESSED");

    private final String status;

    MEDIA_STATUS(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

```
public class Media extends File {
    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper status;
    
    public Media(String pathname) {
        super(pathname);
        this.status = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(MEDIA_STATUS.UNPROCESSED.toString());
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyStringWrapper statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(MEDIA_STATUS status) {
        this.status.set(status.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. and don't name custom classes like framework classes

Comment: The problem was in the updateItem() method. I rewrote it.